# 100% height and width DIV with content in the middle

Tags: html, css

I have searched for a lot of answers to this and tried multiple peoples different solutions but none worked. Does anyone have a simple way of doing this?

Example image:

[image: content in the middle]

The border is meant to be `20px` away from the edge of the browser on all sides. Thank you massively to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sample with the content centered vertically:

**HTML**

```
<div id="box">
    <div id="content">
        Content
    </div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
#box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: solid 5px #CCC;
    margin: 20px;
    position:relative
}
#content {
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top:-10px; /* Should be half of font-size */
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
    font-family: "Helvetica", "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Luxi Sans", Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
```

​Here's the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kf9NP/) code which yield the following result:

[image: Centered content in div]

---

**EDIT** (Alternative if content is more than one line)

Same HTML as before with the following CSS ([demo code](http://jsfiddle.net/Kf9NP/2/)).

```
#box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: solid 5px #CCC;
    margin: 20px;
}
#content {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;

    color: red;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: "Helvetica", "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Luxi Sans", Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
```

[image: Centered three lines content]

Comment: i changed #box to position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
    right:20px;
    bottom:20px; and that works, thank you

Comment: @Alfa3eta If the content is only one line, then it's a working solution, when multiple lines are added, then no, it doesn't work. The problem is you either have to set the width of the child content or use the `display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;` properties. For more than one line of content see the edit.

Answer (score 2):

Try this css on the div:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 20px;
top: 20px;
left: 20px;
right: 20px;
text-align: center;
```

Vertical align problem : As far as i know, you can't use `vertical-align: middle;` on a block. You can fix the problem only with you know the content height (or by using javascript).

You can use `padding-top: 50%;`, but it's not really "middle".

Comment: he also need the content to be in the middle

Comment: thanks that works for the border, now i just need the content in the middle

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat an approach a little more responsive than the one answered above. I hope it helps

**css**

```
#wrapper
{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:20px solid #F82;
}
#content
{
    position:relative;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    height:20%;
    width:20%;
    top:40%;
    color:#E22;
    font-size:40pt;
}
```

​
**html**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">Content</div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Here's a functional [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunovieira/KQ2Mq/)

Comment: the right and bottom borders are off the page, you have to scroll to get them

Comment: i deleted my reply as it didn't actually answer your question, and this one is better.

Answer (score 0):

i updated demo,content in middle also,please see this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d22gs/3/)

```
div{
position:absolute;
text-align:center;
width:100%;
height:100%;
bottom: 20px;
top: 20px;
left: 20px;
right: 20px;
padding:50% 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this css could also work for the content-div

```
position:absolute;
margin-left: 20%;
width: 60% (100%-margin-left*2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>20PX</title>
<style type="text/css">
body{
background-color: blue;}
#test {
position: absolute;
bottom: 20px;
right: 20px;
top: 20px;
left: 20px;
text-align: center;
background-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test">
     center text 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```